# jquery checkbox slow, not sure how to fix

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have used firebug and IE profilers and can see what function in my code is causing the slowness.  Being new to jquery, the recommendations that I have read online are not clear to me.  I have made an example page that shows the slow behavior when you check or uncheck a check box.  No surprise that this is fast using Chrome.

The function that is slow can be found on line 139.

```
$('.filters input').click( function()
```

JSFiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bryan_mee/bSr2X/)

The code is 122 KB and can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0BxD51nP8QBWCOTgyNmUyMTUtNThhOC00NjA1LWE4MjktNjY4NzhmYzhhNGI1&hl=en_US)

UPDATE:  if you know of any examples online that are similar in function and faster,  please share.

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle of this code?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bryan_mee/bSr2X/

Comment: I've only yet taken a quick glance at your code, but this seems like you'll have trouble if you have any states with a space in their names, such as `New York` or `West Virginia`...?

Comment: I know about the space in names issue.  Focusing on slowness first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had a brief look through your code, but it was very hard to follow. it seemed as if you were looping through things many many times. i used a much simpler approach to get the list of all states.

your approach was 
   * make a massive string which contained every class (possibly repeated multiple times)
   * chop it up into an array
   * loop through the array and remove duplicates

i simply took advantage of the fact that when you select something in jQuery you get a set rather than a single item. you can therefore apply changes to groups of object

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //this will hold all our states
    var allStates = [];

    //cache filterable items for future use
    var $itemsToFilter = $(".filterThis");

    //loop through all items. children() is fast because it searches ONLY immediate children
    $itemsToFilter.children("li").each(function() {

        //use plain ol' JS, no need for jQuery to get attribute
        var cssClass = this.getAttribute("class");

        //if we haven't already added the class
        //then add to the array
        if(!allStates[cssClass]) {
             allStates[cssClass] = true;
        }
    });

    //create the container for our filter
    $('<ul class="filters"><\/ul>').insertBefore('.filterThis');

    //cache the filter container for use in the loop
    //otherwise we have to select it every time!
    var $filters = $(".filters");

    // then build the filter checkboxes based on all the class names
    for(var key in allStates) {
        //make sure it's a key we added
        if(allStates.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            //add our filter
            $filters.append('<li><input class="dynamicFilterInput" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="'+key+'" id="filterID'+key+'" /><label for="filterID'+key+'">'+key+'<\/label><\/li>');
        }
    }

    // now lets give those filters something to do
    $filters.find('input').click( function() {
        //cache the current checkbox
        var $this = $(this);

        //select our items to filter
        var $targets = $itemsToFilter.children("li." + $this.val());

        //if the filter is checked, show them all items, otherwise hide
        $this.is(":checked") ? $targets.show() : $targets.hide();

    });
});
```

**FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/bSr2X/6/**

hope that's helpful :)

i noticed it ran quite a bit slower if you tried to slideup all the targets, this is because so many items are being animated at once. you may as well just hide them, since people will only see the ones at the top of the list slide in and out of view, so it's a waste of processor time :)

EDIT: i didn't add logic for show all, but that should be quite a trivial addition for you to make if you follow how i've done it above

Comment: no problem :) does my solution make sense to you? Can you follow it through? Just making sure because it's nothing worse than trying to modify code you don't understand, at some point in future. Do you also understand why it's much more efficient (and readable!) than you original approach? Also, i've done some further updates for further performance improvements. The code and the fiddle have been updated :)

Comment: made *even more* performance improvements. it now appears to be really fast at filtering :) i've not done any actual performance testing, mind you

Comment: I think I understand everything now.  This line if(!allStates[cssClass]) { allStates[cssClass] = true;}  was confusing me, but now I understand it is a hash, not a simple array.

Comment: no it really is a simple array! javascript objects and arrays can use the string indexer notation - you could use an object here instead of an array! i'm using it like a hash though, because we can do a single pass of all items and get a unique list with this approach. it's worth pointing out, if it confused you, that `if(!allStates[cssClass])` is equivalent to `if(!allStates === undefined)`, so it's simply checking i haven't already come across this value previously. it's just a neat shorthand, for obvious reasons be careful using this shorthand with boolean values, however it's fine here.

Answer (score 1):

You could use context with your selector:

```
$('.filters input', '#filters_container').click(function()...
```

this limits the element that jQuery has to look in when selecting elements. Instead of looking at every element in the page, it only looks inside your $('#filters_container') element.

Comment: this particular line you are highlighting here would only benefit once, upon initialization. I think the "slow" problem is happening inside of the click function, not where it is being initially bound...

Comment: How do I get the ie or firebug profiler to show what line is slow?  It does seem to point to the function, not where in the function.